# Replace Value in Numpy array, with Value in a second Numpy array, Given Criteria

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 large arrays with the exact same ammount of elements.

```
Array1=[[1,2,3][1,1,2]]
Array2=[[0,2,0][3,1,3]]
```

if Element in Array1="1", Replace "1" with whatever is in the same place as Array2

```
Output=[[0,2,3][3,1,2]]
```

Should be easy, but this late on a friday has my brains scrambled.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

Array1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,1,2]])
Array2 = np.array([[0,2,0], [3,1,3]])

b = np.where(Array1 == 1)

Array1[b] = Array2[b]
```

Result:

```
>>> Array1
array([[0, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 2]])
```

As jorgeca pointed out the above solution can be reduced to:

```
b = Array1 == 1
Array1[b] = Array2[b]
```

Comment: You could forgo the call to `np.where` (since `Array1 == 1` returns a boolean mask that's already an index) or maybe use its three arguments' form.

Answer (score 2):

This one's based on Akaval's solution, but in one line. It takes advantage of other features of `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np
Array1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,1,2]])  
Array2 = np.array([[0,2,0], [3,1,3]])

Output = np.where(Array1 == 1, Array2, Array1)
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know about this one-line solution. I guess the difference is that this creates a new array instead of modifying Array1.

Comment: @Akavall: I'd actually never heard about `np.where()` until your answer sent me to the documentation. This is actually pretty close to one of the examples on that page.